# Community Engine and tiny mce: undefined local variable or method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, tinymce, rails-engines

I did something that caused this error when loading the home page:

undefined local variable or method
`javascript_include_tiny_mce_if_used'

I'm basically at the beginning of my project. I'm using Rails 2.3, and
worked through debug issues and got the home page and other user
profile loaded fine. I'm working on adding another use case using the
resource_controller plugin, when this error happened and I can't
figure out the source. For some reason it appears CE's tiny_mce plugin
is not loaded, however other plugins are, including haml.

Here's a full stack trace:

```
/Users/dr/myapp/app/views/shared/_scripts_and_styles.html.haml:36:in `_run_haml_app47views47shared47_scripts_and_styles46html46haml_locals_object_scripts_and_styles'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `send'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb:301:in `with_template'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in `render'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:26:in `benchmark'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:26:in `benchmark'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in `render'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/template.rb:194:in `render_template'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in `render_partial'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render_without_haml'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.0.9/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:12:in `render_without_active_scaffold'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.0.9/lib/haml/helpers.rb:57:in `non_haml'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.0.9/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:12:in `render_without_active_scaffold'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/plugins/active_scaffold/lib/extensions/action_view_rendering.rb:61:in `render'
/Users/dr/myapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:12:in `_run_haml_app47views47layouts47application46html46haml'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `send'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb:301:in `with_template'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/template.rb:194:in `render_template'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb:260:in `render_without_haml'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.0.9/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:14:in `render_without_active_scaffold'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/plugins/active_scaffold/lib/extensions/action_view_rendering.rb:61:in `render'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb:347:in `_render_with_layout'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb:257:in `render_without_haml'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.0.9/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:14:in `render_without_active_scaffold'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/plugins/active_scaffold/lib/extensions/action_view_rendering.rb:61:in `render'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1241:in `render_for_file'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:937:in `render_without_benchmark'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_without_active_scaffold'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_without_active_scaffold'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/plugins/active_scaffold/lib/extensions/action_controller_rendering.rb:13:in `render'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1317:in `default_render'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1323:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:638:in `run_before_filters'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/plugins/community_engine/lib/localized_application.rb:22:in `set_locale'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:186:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:635:in `run_before_filters'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:615:in `call_filters'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:141:in `perform_action'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:523:in `send'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:523:in `process_without_filters'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `sass_old_process'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/haml-2.0.9/lib/sass/plugin/rails.rb:19:in `process'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:433:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:88:in `dispatch'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:111:in `_call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:82:in `initialize'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/rewindable_input.rb:25:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/session/abstract_store.rb:122:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:9:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:11:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/chunked.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:61:in `process'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:34:in `run'
/Users/dr/myapp/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:111
/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
```

Answer (score 0):

A stacktrace would be very helpful in investigating your problem.  Also, if you are properly using SCM with small & independent commits, you may want to look back through to see what code changes you've made that caused the problem.  I'm afraid that without details, I can't provide a more specific answer.